# Realistic Human Skin in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I have a character with some strange textures, and I don't know how to use them. For example for face i have these files:

```
face_D.tga
face_L.tga
face_M.tga
face_N.tga
face_S.tga
```

Now, I need a node map, so I can put everything in it's right place, but I have no idea about what I need to do, because I'm too new to Blender and Material Nodes.
I want to use all of these files to create a realistic human skin material.

Comment: Where did you get these map?

Comment: @JachymMichal Oops!, of course you can.  I was imagining setting radii by hand? I'll get to it as soon as I can. In the mean time, Axel can pick up your adjustment. So you reckon that red map is RGB SS radii, not RGB SS color? It seems odd to have SS color the same as surface color?

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, it's seems odd at first. But that's just how SSS is implemented in Principled BSDF. The Subsurface slider actually multiplies the radius *and also* mixes Base and Subsurface colors. Other engines (V-Ray, Renderman, Arnold) have these as two separate sliders.

Comment: That's why I'm here ... I learn something every day  I grew up doing it with Mental Ray!!!

Comment: <tears of joy> Robin Betts just learned something new from me :).</joy> I just realized Mental Ray was discontinued long before I even started with 3D, you're like a wise elder around here :).

Comment: @JachymMichal  I've written you a small essay in a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108346/sss-in-principled-bsdf).. actually, I probably wrote it for _me_, but anyway, there it is.

Comment: Everyone lessen !  you guys are making me confusing , well , let me say again , anyone is here who can set these texture on their right nodes ? if there is so please send an photo for me to see how should it be. plus , Im Extra noob at blender.

Comment: @RobinBetts , thanks very very much for that , well i used your nodes , and i worked on it , but the skin will stay full white. i removed AO so skin came back but , its not still looking real enough.

Comment: @RobinBetts i wish i could , but belongs to my friend and i don't have that permission. i asked but didn't let. thats why its making my work hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a shot at what your tree might look like, as corrected by @Jachym.

[image]

- Introduce the branches one at a time,starting with Diffuse color on its own.
- Unlike the illustration, forget the AO branch to begin with. Plug the Diffuse map straight into the Base Color.
- Then check the Normal. If you want to get a better view, you can temporarily unplug the Diffuse map to see  the effect on a white object.
- When that's OK, plug the Diffuse back in, and go for the Shininess.
- Now go for the Subsurface Scattering. Split the Diffuse, and plug it into Subsurface Color too.
- Plug the 'M' map into the Subsurface Radius.
- Depending on the size of your model, adjust the 'Subsurface' slider down. (I would recommend scaling the model in Edit mode, to life-size, in whatever units your scene is in.) Plugged in as shown, the RGB values in the red 'M' map represent the distances R,G and B are allowed to scatter through the object, in Blender Units, before attenuating to 0. Those distances are then multiplied by the value in the 'Subsurface' slider.

This is hard to check without the file.. but I hope it heads in the right direction.

- If you really need the AO, (the lighting shouldn't really need faking..), use an RGB Mix node set to 'Multiply' or 'Overlay' to mix it with the Diffuse map on the way into the Base Color.

There's every chance @Jachym will have to correct me again :)

Comment: i tried but couldn't get my desire result. i uploaded an file so you can see it better. link is up in my question. Thanks by the way. ;)

Comment: @Axel     I've had a go, [here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2eZQR5JB/). Tweaking would be a matter of taste .. the Normal maps aren't perfect.. seams are showing a bit.. and the fingernails, being part of the same SSS object, don't block the SS scattering through the fingers. If your privacy is important, I can delete this comment with its link at your request.

Comment: i give up on this , looks like this not gonna be fixed. i'll give it back to owner. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Not ooking OK in the .blend I sent?

Comment: @Axel Perhaps you expected a stronger effect :). But scattering is *very subtle* (almost imperceptible) on a single hand with spread fingers. Robin's setup gives very realistic results.

Comment: @JachymMichal I judged it by backlighting the hand.. it's actually too much, IMO.. If the fingernails stopped it, that would help.

Comment: I also noticed *Random Walk* sss method works great here (especially for the thin nails), and isn't much slower :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Crikey! There you go! Another lesson from JM! :)You really should have been answering this one.

Comment: i know with an hand is very hard , but i can't send whole character , even , im trying to process whatever you guys say on character face with any change that i can , but it alwasy looks like the same face , i need something powerful like Emily 2.1 model , which i never couldnt understand it.

Comment: @Axel.. have you tried downloading the .blend in my comment, above?

Comment: @Axel To better understand SSS, you can also check this thread: [Rules and presets for SSS in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972).

Comment: @RobinBetts Of course i did , 2 times i did XD , but guess what , I DID IT NOW !!!! little change in your nodes + my details made it Perfect ! not as much as emily but very acceptable. THANKS BIG MAN !!!!! Now i have lotta new question in my new posts. u gotta answer them all. ur cool.

Comment: @Axel.. Yay! .. I think I've learned more from this question than you have, thanks to JM.

Comment: @RobinBetts YEA , ur right we all did , Thanks to all !