# How to use Subsurface Scattering in Principled BSDF

Tags: materials, shaders, subsurface-scattering

The Subsurface Scattering in Principled BSDF is a bit confusing:

- Where can I find some material presets?
- What is the difference between Scattering Color and Radius?

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Subsurface amount

- Use it to scale Scattering depth down to realistic values
- When set to 0, scattering is disabled

> Values of around 0.01 are normal, since you're scaling from *meters to milimeters*

### Subsurface Radius (aka Scatter Color)

- Visible on edges and translucent parts (like ears and fingers)
- Connect an RGB node or a texture. This is a good place for a subdermal map
- The RGB values represent how deep light penetrates *in meters*

> Scale the radius down using the *Subsurface slider*

### Subsurface Color

- Visible on opaque parts and in shadows
- Use the same image/color you used for *Base color* to avoid color mixing

### Subsurface Anisotropy

- Bias between forward-scattering rays and backward-scattering rays
- Realistic skin has an anisotropy around 0.8

---

### Example of Subsurface Scattering Result

[image]

### Easy to use chart

(just drag it into image editor and colorpick the values)

[image]

---

### Subsurface Scattering values

- Drag the chart into Blender's image editor and use color picker to select colors
- For SSS to work correctly, your model needs to be in real world scale.

[image]

<sub><sup>[Source chart from Pixar](https://rmanwiki.pixar.com/display/REN22/Subsurface+Scattering+Parameters). Original paper [here](http://www.graphics.stanford.edu/papers/bssrdf/)</sup></sub>.

---

*Sources*

<sub><sup>[Link](http://www.graphics.stanford.edu/papers/bssrdf/) -
Henrik Wann Jensen, Stephen R. Marschner, Marc Levoy and Pat Hanrahan: "A Practical Model for Subsurface Light Transport". SIGGRAPH'2001.

[An Introduction To Real-Time Subsurface Scattering](https://therealmjp.github.io/posts/sss-intro/), [Stanford Dragon - Stanford University Computer Graphics Laboratory](http://graphics.stanford.edu/data/3Dscanrep/), [Subsurface - Arnold Renderer](https://docs.arnoldrenderer.com/display/A5AFMUG/Subsurface), [Subsurface - Substance Painter](https://docs.substance3d.com/spdoc/subsurface-material-type-172818959.html), [Subsurface - Renderman](https://rmanwiki.pixar.com/display/REN22/Subsurface+Scattering+Parameters)</sup></sub>

Comment: Love it. Many thanks!

Comment: This answer should be edited into the blender manual.

Comment: Here is a blender file that you can link that has many of these materials defined. [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=s2XSDAyl" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/s2XSDAyl/)