# Need help on the pear materials and lights setup

Tags: materials, light

As you can see, I am trying to make the image on the left looked like the one on the right. But the light and pear are way far from the goal. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

[image]

This is the pear's material. So far there is only one point light.

[image]

Comment: Subjectively, adding some variation on the roughness.

Comment: Hello, good job so far :). If I may suggest, correct SSS values are important for photorealism. This thread should help: [Rules and presets for SSS in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972)

Comment: Thanks a lot @JachymMichal. It helps.