# SSS not working correctly on this model (cycles)

Tags: subsurface-scattering

I've been working on uv unwrapping and retexturing this model from Daz, unfortunately, the SSS doesn't seem to work right in Cycles. It seems to be somehow inverted, as the main head is more transparent than the ears, nose, etc. I have it set to Random walk, and have no idea why its acting this way and what could be the root cause of it

[image: here it is with subsurface set to 1 so you can see what I'm talking about]

[image: see how it looks wrong even with a lower value]

Comment: 1 is a rather strong value for SSS. Good results are often achieved with subsurface values around 0.1 - 0.3. Maybe try turning down the strength and see if that helps?

Comment: no no, you misunderstand. I usually do input the subsurface value around that. The problem is that the SSS is being calculated wrong, the head is having light shine through it while things like the ears, lips, and eyelids don't. Its very weird. I can send you the blend file if it helps visualize it

Comment: Oh. I see. Yeah I'm not sure about that. Unfortunately I can't test tonight (even with your file) because I have a dead GPU. I have a new one coming tomorrow - if you still have no answer by then, I'll be happy to have a look.

Comment: Hello :). Your Scattering depth is set to 1 meter. Either scale up the model or decrease the SSS value to 0,001 (milimeters)

Comment: Related: [Rules and presets for SSS](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972)

Comment: I know that its set too high. I don't typically use it that high, I just set it to maximum to illustrate the problem. The problem is that the SSS is being calculated wrong, the head is having light shine through it while things like the ears, lips, and eyelids don't. I can send you the file if it helps you understand what is going on.

Comment: Hey, I'm back. I got my new GPU so I'm back in business! If you want to post your file, I'll have a look and see if I can find anything.