# Greenish tone after rendering

Tags: rendering, color

I'm doing the Blender Guru donut tutorial as I'm learning blender. I've texture painted my donut dough in brown but when I render it with cycles, it has a greenish tone.

[Here](https://b97479935-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/mats_acerta-cert_es/EmBiB7Xcd21FkOZMu3saXg4B5VjNztxMIz4WjLM0g21I2g?e=yFqvNi) is the project uploaded to OneDrive.

Here you can see the material preview
[image]

Here you can see the render preview
[image]

Here you can see the final render
[image]

I would appreciate some help very much. Thanks in advance!

P.D.: before starting this question I touched something (don't know what and now the background is white and everything "has more light" and the icing looks faker. How do I turn it back?

Comment: The greenish color is caused by the Subsurface Scattering in Material.003. Try lowering Subsurface Radius (0.100 , 0.020 , 0.010 looks good imho)

Comment: Related: [Rules and presets for SSS in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972)