# I messed something with color (principled BSDF?) and I don't know whats wrong

Tags: rendering, color

I was attempting to make a chocolate chip  but it renders like a ghostly mint-chocolate. I recently made a doughnut and was trying to make something similar on my own. What should I do to fix it?[image]

Comment: Hello, looks like you messed with the subsurface scattering settings. They are great for organic objects but you have to tweak them with caution. Try from scratch with a brand new principled bsdf node (Add > Shader > Principled) and tweak the setting little by little to see the effects

Comment: This thread might help with SSS settings: [Rules and presets for SSS in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972)

Comment: Wow, Thank you both! I was not expecting a reply so quick

Comment: @JachymMichal How did I never see that ? Thanks :)