# How do I create material like this?

Tags: texturing, materials, light, texture-painting

This is the cover of the mixtape "&&&&&" by musician Arca.

I've been fascinated by the aesthetic of it and want to try similar stuff, but i am quite the beginner when it comes to Blender, so I don't know how to create something like this in terms of the material (it looks almost wet, or just very shiny) and the light (I think it makes the image look quite realistic, almost like a photo).

Maybe you can help me... thx in advance!

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to use Subsurface Scattering in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be unique and identifying and summarize what the issue is, so that visitors can at a glance understand broadly what your post is about from the question list. Please use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors will see, and weights on their decision to open your question or not, so the number of answers you might get depends heavily on it.

Answer (score 2):

It strikes me as a two point lighting setup, where both lights are slightly behind the model giving the front a heavy shadow.  This is a top-down view of my sample scene.

[image]

I couldn't get anywhere close with a material until I started messing around with some very strange SSS values.

[image]

My world lighting doesn't match the reference, and it may have been taken into the compositor for some color correction.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Allen's answer I too went into the SSS rabbit hole... :)
You can actually get close with reasonable amounts of scattering.

Basic SSS principles apply

- Subsurface Color - visible in shadows
- SS Radius (Scatter color) - visible on edges and backlit parts
- Used Random Walk method for SSS (slower but more precise)

<sup>Yeah I slapped a mickey mouse face there so it looks more cute</sup>
[image]

[image]

Comment: that look really nice! the brain-looking thing on the side also looks quite 'wet'... did you also get that with adjusting the light?

Comment: Glad you like how gross it is :). The 'wetness' is due to low Roughness value. The color variation in ridges/valleys is caused by Subsurface Scattering.