# How do I recreate this translucent/subsurface material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, subsurface-scattering

[image]

I thought it'd be rather simple as it just looks like something with a lot of roughness and subsurface, but I can't get it to work somehow. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? Can you show a node setup of what you have done so far? Or how it looks rendered? Things like subsurface scattering can also look very different depending on the environment, lighting etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

edit subsurface radius. this is the most overlooked sss settings in blender.
do note that before that you need to apply scale on model to get same results on every model that has this values.

[image]

Comment: Those settings aswell as changing the lighting worked wonders. I was only using hdri lighting. Adding an actual lamp helped a lot.

Comment: Perhaps related: [How to use Subsurface Scattering in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972)