# Blue glow bleeding around hair (repost with screenshot)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, light

this is a repost of an issue that I failed to provide a screenshot for. I am using blender 2.81 with eevee rendering, and every time I add hair of any color, there is this weird bluish glow around it. I have tried disabling screenspace reflections, tried changing the color of the hair, and even checked to see if bloom was enabled. I'm wondering if this is an undiscovered bug with eevee. Any help fixing this annoying issue would be much appreciated.

[image: Unwanted blue glow around hair in eevee]

Comment: My guess is you have your Subsurface Scattering values too high on your "head".  0.05 - 0.35 is generally the range that looks best for most things (without artefacts).

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179560/how-to-use-subsurface-scattering-in-principled-bsdf/179561#179561

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Hello, Duarte. Please do not comment just to tell me not to repost a question. If you don't have a genuine answer, then don't comment at all.