# How do i create this smoothie texture for mantaflow liquids?

Tags: texturing, materials, particles, mantaflow

[image: The smoothie texture]

[image: Whole reference image]

Hi, im trying to make a fluid simulation for a smoothie commercial but im having trouble recreating the exact texture. Any help would be appreciated.

[image] here is the blend file

Comment: You haven't shown any research or progress to meet this goal, would you mind adding further details about your previous efforts

Comment: So far i've tried mixing two Principled BSDF shaders with a noise texture as the factor. Seems to me that the issue is to replicate the graininess and bubbly look that it has. I've tried adding bubble particles but that didn't work out. Sorry, im not too sure where to start, im pretty new to mantaflow, i could send in the .blend file perhaps? Im just doing some tests and practices.

Comment: sure post it to paste all

Comment: i just edited the post to include it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this. It's just 3 Voronoi Textures (of varying sizes) with their vectors warped slightly by a Noise Texture so they don't create such "uniformly circular" dots.

The largest Voronoi, I used to represent "big fruit bits" floating in the background, and gave them some varying color to the base, so they make subtle "lumps" of color.

The middle Voronoi Texture I used to give the "black bits" as well as color the main "liquid" more green. I mixed this color with the background fruit, and still unhappy with the result, I used a Hue/Saturation/Value node to desaturate the color slightly, and tint it a bit more to the blue side.

I simply used the top Voronoi texture to add "white pulp bits" to the final result. I increased the roughness *very* slightly, and gave it a small subsurface value to mimic the liquid. It may or may not be needed - just keep the value low (<0.2) to keep it realistic.

[image: Juice]

Comment: Subsurface is very common in foods - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179560/how-to-use-subsurface-scattering-in-principled-bsdf

Comment: That looks amazing, thank you so much for sharing. I have a lot to learn about nodes, will be trying this out now.