# How to make light go through this subsurface scattering object in Eevee

Tags: mesh, materials, eevee-render-engine, lighting, subsurface-scattering

Blender 2.93 I have this cat ear, and i want the light to go through it until it hits the front face, the material is subsurface scattering and i enabled Subsurface translucency in material, but the light wont go through it until the front face.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to use Subsurface Scattering in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cat ear has a height of 14 meters. If you had a real mount of flesh that size, there wouldn't scatter much light through it either. So make it smaller to have it more real-life scale or change the value for *Subsurface* to something higher. The slider won't go higher than 1, but you can enter a value manually. Here's an example with *Subsurface* = 10:

[image: subsurface translucency]

By the way, that size is also the reason you have to set your point light to such a ridiculously high strength of 90950 W. If the ear was 0.14 m instead of 14 m and the light in the same relation 0.1 m away from it instead of 10 m, it would like pierce through it and make it glow bright white ;)