# Subsurface Scattering (SSS) doesn't work

Tags: shaders, subsurface-scattering

I followed the following tutorial: "[Blender Day 4 - Shading/Texturing/UV - Introduction Series for Beginners](https://youtu.be/qsXlL1WXEQA?t=1797)"

Unfortunately, the Subsurface Scattering doesn't work (see picture below). I also tried this tutorial "[[2.93] Blender Tutorial: Quick Subsurface Scattering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItaZUZIiNmk)"

But it doesn't work as well...I don't know why. Hope someone could help me.
What I did: I created the cheese and added in Shading a Subsurface Scattering (see picture below). Not more...sorry I'm a beginner, so I have no more information to say :(

File added: [image]

[image: cheese model]

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by the Subsurf doesn't work? You've assigned a Subsurf modifier to the object and it doesn't get round? Could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots I think he's talking about subsurface scattering, not subdivision surface. People started calling subdivision surface 'Subsurface' for short, but it gets confused with actual subsurface (scattering).

Comment: @ Alexandre Marcati oh ok thanks for the precision

Comment: @moonboots the question is about the *Subsurface Scattering*. The shader result doesn't look like cheese.

Comment: it looks like we can see a bit of SSS? @Sven S. maybe share your file?

Comment: My first thought is maybe the cheese object is out of scale, too big. Like several meters big. That would make the subsurface scattering hard to notice because the light wouldn't get through.

Comment: One question: why are you using the Susurface Scattering node instead of just using the subsurface scattering in the principled BSDF node?

Comment: @Alexandre Marcati Yes :) Thanks for this information. My object was too big (11m). I changed the sice to 1.5m and it looks better. But not like the one in the video.
I used the Subsuf insted the principle BSDF only for the test. I hoped to see a different.

Comment: Isn't 1.5m still way too big for a piece of cheese? It's not a complete wheel of cheese, is it? The settings for the SSS and the light depend on the size of the model. I would scale down the cheese to real-world size. In the N-panel on the right in the viewport you see the *Scale* and *Dimension*. Make sure the scale doesn't get negative. Apply the *Scale* (Ctrl+A) to reset it to 1.000. Then you can use the 0.045 value for the SSS. Try 250W for the spotlight. Make the radius smaller and move it closer (~2m). Make sure Cycles & 'Rendered' shading are used =>https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRVXu.jpg

Comment: @SvenS. i'd recommend making the cheese as close to real-life scale as possible. A piece of cheese like that would be around 10cm tall at most, I think. Unless there's a reason to make it so big. 1.5m is almost as big as person.
The larger the object, the harder it is to notice SSS, because the light doesn't get through. The smaller/thinner the object, the more light gets through, so the SSS is more noticeable.
If there's a reason the cheese has to be gigantic, you can try and crank up the subsurface scattering value until you get the result you want.

Comment: Thanks booth (Blunder and Alexandre) for your instruction. It looks much better. Also the hint wirh the scale. But I don't understand, why my cheese doesn't look like the one in the tutorial. This one looks like more "wet".

I know I habe much more to lern in blender :) belssendly I have this forum

Comment: Oh, you're right. Cheese has fat and this makes the cheese look shiny/glossy/wet. Just lower the *Roughness* value and increase the *Specular* value as shown in the first video. I'll post a summary as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things that you need to fix.

**1. Make the Model Real-World Size**

> I'd recommend making the cheese as close to real-life scale as possible. A piece of cheese like that would be around 10cm tall at most, I think. Unless there's a reason to make it so big. 1.5m is almost as big as a person. The larger the object, the harder it is to notice SSS, because the light doesn't get through. The smaller/thinner the object, the more light gets through, so the SSS is more noticeable. If there's a reason the cheese has to be gigantic, you can try and crank up the subsurface scattering value until you get the result you want.
> - *Alexandre Marcati*

Additionally, if you want to see the "light passes through" effect, you should craete a slice of cheese, not a block of cheese.

In the left bottom corner of the screenshot, you can see the dimensions. I've cut your cheese *block* in half and added a few more holes (*Boolean* modifier).

[image: screenshot]

**2. Subsurface Scattering Settings**
You messed the settings a bit up. The radius is set to 1.0, 1.0, 0.1 in your blend file. This changes the color mix of the base color and the subsurface color and the result is not what you expect.

As a guide, you can try values from this chart:
[How to use Subsurface Scattering in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179561/107598)

**3. Roughness and Specular**
To make the fat of cheese a bit more prominent and the cheese shinier, just lower the *Roughness* value of the *Principled BSDF* node. Increase the *Specular* value if you like. For more realistic results, you can add a *Noise Texture*.

**4. Light**
To see the "light passes through" effect place a light source behind the object. In the example and the linked video, the sunrise HDRI that is included in Blender is used. You can choose it in the viewport shading option. And also use it as your scene background in the render: [How to use 2.8's default HDRi's in renders?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/128503/107598).