# Red/Blue Tint in Supposedly All White Scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, color

I was trying to create a cup with milk in it but for some reason there seems to be a red tint at the top of the cup and even a blue tint at the bottom of the cup. I want the material/lighting to be all white. Attached are images from both the render viewport and rendered image
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using Subsurface Scattering? In that case, in the Principled BSDF (or SSS node), you need to check the Subsurface Radius settings (it's in RGB, lower down the first value if the color is too redish)

Comment: Hello :). This sometimes happens when using Subsurface Scattering with too high values. But hard to tell, you didn't share your milk material ;)

Comment: I'll second on the subsurface radius - default values allow more red to pass deeper (because SSS was originally built with skin in mind). For milk, make them all 0.8 or so - for skim milk, maybe even give blue (third value) a slightly higher value than red or green.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179561/110840