# Texture turning green in rendered view

Tags: texturing

After doing the donut tutorial, I decided to make a bagel. I started to do the displacement and was watching the displacement tutorial, but when I switched to render view it turned a greenish color. The material preview mode still shows the normal bagel color. Any idea what's going on?[image: Nodes][image: Rendered view][image: Material preview]

Comment: hello, please pack your image and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi :). Your subsurface scattering is set to 10 centimeters which is too much, and might be causing color changes. Related: [How to use Subsurface Scattering in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972)

Comment: That was the issue, thanks so much!