# How to get rid of the blue shadow around intersecting particles?

Tags: mesh, objects, particles, image, shadows

[image: Example - blue shadow around intersecting particles]I usually like to sculpt parts of my meshes separately and assemble them together for easier modifiaction later on. But I usually notice a blue shadow around separate intersecting meshes or particles in the rendered image. Example image attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an artifact of subsurface scattering. Consider using a different subsurface radius

[image: Default subsurface radius]
[image: Even subsurface radius]

Comment: a value of 1 here is 1 meter by default ;)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179560/how-to-use-subsurface-scattering-in-principled-bsdf