# skin material gives a green-ish tint because of hair material, how can I resolve this?

Tags: materials

Sorry this is a silly problem :/ which I can't resolve.

I geuss some light "diffuse" through the hair and leave the skin a green-ish tint, which is undesirable. Can I somehow let skin material and hair material don't interact with each other?

below picture is the node setting for the skin material.
[image: node setting for skin material]

below picture is the node setting for the hair material + hide hair, as you can see, the green tint is gone.
[image: node setting for hair material]

ps. I thought the outcome would look better but it literally looks like an inflatable doll. Epic fail.

Comment: it is greenish thanks to the subsurface scattering value and I'm not sure you can just switch hair off that in some efficient way ... so first try to change SSS strength or you have just wrong SSS color coming from HUE node ... so try to change that.

Comment: related: [How to use Subsurface Scattering in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972)