# Subsurface Scattering Causes Strange Dark Sections

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, artifacts, subsurface-scattering

I am working on a model and I am using subsurface scattering for the skin. It was working well until I got to the face. When I added subsurface scattering, it caused the section around the mouth and eyes to become dark and bluish. The only way I can find to fix it is by deleting the mesh for the mouth and teeth, but I need those meshes. I have tried adding subsurface scattering to the mouth mesh, and disconnecting it from the body mesh, but nothing has worked. Also, the effect does not show in material preview, only in rendered view. Thank you in advance! [image: Viewport VS. Rendered]

Comment: Looks like your subsurface is set too high, the value is a 'scale' setting that determines how far into the mesh light can penetrate, .19 is about 7 inches :p

Comment: At that point the ray may never make it back to a light, and will be reported as lost (black pixel), since that is probabilistic based on ray direction, this causes an overall darkening in color

Comment: Thank you so much! What would be a good value for it?

Comment: Okay so I changed the subsurface value to 0.05, but the dark color is definitely still there especially around the eyes...it does not go away until subsurface is zero. Also, I can get the darkness around the mouth to disappear by deleting the mouth mesh from the body, but I need the mouth. Here is what it looks like with subsurface at 0.05: https://imgur.com/a/pR0k5wU

Comment: Try the settings here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179561/110840

Comment: Unfortunately still having the same problem...

Comment: This might have something to do with the thickness of the mesh, missing faces on the inside, or clipping, and might be hard to solve without getting very specific detail.  Suggest you give it some thought and [edit] the post with more info if you find it worthwhile.  Cheers

Comment: Alright, so I have found that when I delete the mouth mesh the problem stops, and here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/ZzlAszi Also, for anyone who could possibly investigate further here is the .blend file: https://mega.nz/file/ZzwE3SYT#ImBsfZaG_rAs0n6xmn8Jv9C9KZtgeQkGDeur6RaCURE