# Subsurface Scattering (SSS) isn't working

Tags: subsurface-scattering

I'm a new blender user and I'm following the donut tutorial. I'm trying to give my donut SSS using the cycles render engine, but it doesn't seem to be working.

In my donut material I've applied the SSS settings but still have the output of a plain old donut with no light coming through. If I've missed any details let me know, thanks!

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried increasing the value? at some point it should start getting red

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it just didn't get any better

Comment: Hi :). The SSS probably works, but the depth is around 0,1 mm which is hardly noticeable. There's also some difference between how Eevee and Cycles handle SSS ;)

Comment: Related: [How to use Subsurface Scattering in Principled BSDF](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179561/78972)