# Cycles render problem: overexposed edges

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I believe that the problem is in render settings, but I am not sure. I tried to reduce/change light power, but it does not help.

Help me guys!

[image]

This is the material:

[image]

Comment: Hello. It looks like subsurface scattering, almost like your material is made out of flesh. Can you post a screenshot of the shader node tree ?

Comment: Sure! https://imgtr.ee/i/d76Tz

Comment: Yup, definitely subsurface. You need to reduce the values coming into the subsurface color by a lot, they are counted in Blender units (or meters if you're real-life scale) so a white value means that subsurface rays will traverse 1 m into your mesh (not exactly though, but I think it's a good enough explanation)

Comment: Related to @Gorgious comment: [How to use Subsurface Scattering](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/179560/78972)