# Blurry (Not pixelated) black spots on my surface using only Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I have been trying to render my doughnut. However, I have been experiencing difficulties when I use Cycles. The doughnut would have blurry black spots whenever I was using Cycles to render. This doesn't happen when using Eevee. The render settings and also the screenshot using render viewport is provided (same effect with render viewport or normal renders)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, could you provide a screenshot of your icing's material please?

Comment: Hello, the icing material is within the post after I re-edited it. Thank you!

Comment: Does the icing intersect with the doughnut mesh? Cycles uses volumetric subsurface scattering, so weird things can happen when there is a surface inside of the scattering volume. This is a common problem with skin, such as where lips touch and joints bend inward. You can check if this is the issue by hiding the doughnut mesh. If it's still happening, check if the icing intersects with itself.

Comment: Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @SupaKoopaTroopa64 I hided the doughnut mesh and rendered with only the icing. The problem still exists. How do I check the icing intersects with itself?

Comment: @moonboots I don't think that's possible, as the files are too big to send through. There is an entire scene with other objects included within the project. However, no other objects during rendering have this problem.

Comment: only keep the donut and its icing and share?

Comment: Maybe not the cause of the issue, but that's definitely too high of a subsurface value, usually we use values around 0.01. See [materials - How to use Subsurface Scattering in Principled BSDF - Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/179561/53447). If you want translucency (which isn't really common in icings i think), adding a Translucent BSDF to your shader would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you all; by disabling the subsurface value, I was able to make the donut render as I intended. Thanks for all your help and contribution

Comment: @Outsidermm I don't really know if there is an easy way to tell if a mesh intersects with itself besides looking very closely. Another thing that might be the problem is that your scattering depth is higher that the thickness of your mesh. I don't know how thick the icing is, but assuming the doughnut is the size of the default torus, I'd guess the icing is 30-50mm thick. Dividing your scattering amount by about 5 might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your input! I was able to resolve this issue by turning down the subsurface value.

Answer (score 0):

Check your topology. Black spots usually mean bad topology. If not that, then mess around with the subsurf value.
EDIT
Ok, I know one other solution. Turn up your transparency bounces until the black portion goes away. Maybe you can send a picture of your donut in edit mode as well?

For the transparency bounces, go to RenderProperties > LightBounces

Comment: What does topology specifically mean? I am a beginner, so I don't really know. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hello, Fanimation, this really needs fleshing out to be considered a truly helpful answer, IMO. For completion, I think you'd need to illustrate _how_ bad topology can look like this. (Incidentally, this effect looks more like an anomaly arising from Subsurface Scattering settings .. but of course, I could be wrong)

Comment: Yes, thats right @RobinBetts

Comment: Topology is generally how cleanly or uniform the object has been modelled with consideration of vertex and edge spacing in relation to each other on a per model basis and clean edge loops in models which are going to animate or deform. The comment does need more clarification but I suspect they're referring to making sure there are no open faces, duplicate vertices/edges/faces which can cause a similar rendering effect. I've found Blender does this a lot when you're chopping and changing your models, especially when doing boolean operations and merge vertices operations sometimes don't work.