How to stop subsurface scattering when I paint my sculpt

I painted some black spots with the Paint brush in sculpting mode and as you can see in the Cycles viewport the subsurface scattering is going crazy.

the Subsurface Scattering value of 1.0 (Weight in Blender 4.x) is probably too high  for a skin texture. The value depends on the size of the model. Common skin values for real-world-sized humans are 0.01. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/179560/how-to-use-subsurface-scattering-in-principled-bsdf. With a weight of 1.0, you get something like the wax of a candle.

okay, got it! thank you very much!

I agree that 1.0 might be too high, but this looks very bright in those spots. Have you accidentally painted black spots in the Alpha channel so that the material is now transparent there?
